# Multiple using of || and && operands

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a query using Entity Framework. It has many different operands and I am confused with its priority. I am getting the wrong result. I need all records that `IsPaid == true` or `IsPaid == null`, also all records must be `TypeId == 1` or `TypeId == 2`, also must be `CityId == 1` and `CategoryId == 2`. For some reason it doesn't evaluate `CityId` and `CategoryId`.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
var list = db.Ads.Where (x =>
               x.IsPaid == true || x.IsPaid == null &&
               x.TypeId == 1 || x.TypeId == 2 &&
               x.CityId == 1 && x.CategoryId == 2
).ToList();
```

Comment: group them logically

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages

Comment: Read up on operator precedence and group them accordingly.

Comment: Who on earth writes `x.IsPaid == true` when one can write `x.IsPaid`? I've never understood such statements.

Comment: @UweKeim: Could be a `bool?`, perhaps. Note the `null` check afterwards. `bool?` is not implicitly convertible into `bool`. Another way to have only a single check would be `x.IsPaid != false` , though.

Comment: I have `public Nullable<bool> IsPaid { get; set; }`

Comment: You would be advised to study basic boolean algebra and propositional calculus. It's really very interesting, IMO.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is using brackets.
You should always use them even if you know the binding prioritys, to increase readability of your code.

```
(x.IsPaid == true || x.IsPaid == null) && (x.TypeId == 1 || x.TypeId == 2) && x.CityId == 1 && x.CategoryId == 2
```

`&&` has a higher proirity than `||`

So `false && false || true` would be translated to `(false && false) || true` => `true`

Sidenote as mentioned by @Joey:

Instead of `(x.IsPaid == true || x.IsPaid == null)` you can write `(x.IsPaid != false)`.

Comment: I have `public Nullable<bool> IsPaid { get; set; }` . Anyway thanks!

Comment: Right, dind´t think about that possibility, edited my answer.

Comment: You're right, `&&` has higher priority than `||`, but I propose to use brackets always, so instead of ´A && B || C´, I propose to write `(A && B) || C`. Although it means exactly the same, it heavily improves readability by removing possible doubts.

Comment: Watch out with your final comment, I don't know if this applies for EF, but in LINQ-to-SQL, `IsPaid != false` will be translated to `IsPaid <> 0`, whereas `(IsPaid || IsPaid == null)` will be translated to `(IsPaid = 1 OR IsPaid IS NULL)`, which is *not* equivalent at all.

Comment: A nullable bool can have the value `true`, `false ` or `null`. so `bool != false` will be `true`for `true`and `null`, which is exactly the same as `bool || bool == null`

Comment: Yes, that's definitely true in C#, but notoriously *not* in SQL, where a null does *not* compare equal to itself. See the [three-valued logic section here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)). If you want to check if a column is null in SQL, you have to use a different syntax (`col IS NULL` instead of `col = NULL`). That's why I was saying it's *not* the same thing in the case of SQL. I don't know how EF translates the query to SQL, but if it behaves the same way as linq-to-sql, you'll need to keep the separate null check if you want to keep the same semantics.

Answer (score 9):

Due to [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence), `&&` binds higher than `||`.

If you chain Where statements, it's more clear what happens:

```
var list = db.Ads
          .Where(x => x.IsPaid == true || x.IsPaid == null)
          .Where(x=> x.TypeId == 1 || x.TypeId == 2)
          .Where(x=> x.CityId == 1)
          .Where(x=> x.CategoryId == 2)
          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

`&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, just like in math. So, effectively your condition is the following:

```
x.IsPaid == true ||
x.IsPaid == null && x.TypeId == 1 ||
x.TypeId == 2 && x.CityId == 1 && x.CategoryId == 2
```

If any of those expressions on separate lines are true, the whole expression is true. You have to use parentheses to clarify here:

```
(x.IsPaid == true || x.IsPaid == null) &&
(x.TypeId == 1 || x.TypeId == 2) &&
 x.CityId == 1 &&
 x.CategoryId == 2
```

Comment: "just like in math": I had a fair amount of math in high school and college, but I certainly never absorbed any standard precedence for *and* and *or* until I started programming.

Comment: @phoog: In logic the precedence for ∧ and ∨ is certainly the same. You have to use parentheses to clarify sometimes (which makes the conjunctive normal form particularly annoying to write). Often you can also shorten things by leaving out the ∧ symbol, contracting just like with multiplication where you'd leave out ⋅ between variables.

Comment: So what operators are you referring to when you say "just like in math"?

Comment: @phoog: ∧ and ∨, as noted.

Comment: But your answer says "has a higher precedence ... just like in math" while your comment says "the precedence ... is the same."  It can't be both higher and the same.

Comment: @phoog: The precedence for ∧ and ∨ *in math* is the same *as in most/all programming languages, i.e. ∧ has a higher precedence than ∨*. Apologies for the unclear wording.

Comment: Ah! That makes much more sense, thanks :)  I wasn't challenging the fact that the precedence is the same in programming as in math; I just wanted to point out that "just like in math" would have been useless to me as a beginning programmer, as I'd never done enough logic to retain the knowledge, and didn't get around to learning it until I started programming.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var list = db.Ads.Where (
            (x => x.IsPaid == true || x.IsPaid == null) && 
            (x.TypeId == 1 || x.TypeId == 2) && 
            (x.CityId == 1 && x.CategoryId == 2)
).ToList();
```